# Can I use the Java timer class for timed data collection?

Tags: java, timer

I am writing a program that collects a series of angle inputs during a trial and saves these to a file with their corresponding timestamps.

For example:

1 sec   260 degrees

2 sec   45 degrees

3 sec   60 degrees

etc.

When running a trial, the user should be able to pause and restart or fully abort the trial if need be.

I am running into trouble with the pause functionality.  I have been using the Java Timer and TimerTask classes to time the input, as it provides much of the functionality I am looking for (start a task after a delay, only record data at certain intervals, etc.).

Within my timerTask, I have been storing the collected angles and times in parallel arrays, and then at the end of the trial, writing these arrays to a file.

However, when I "pause" my timerTask via the timer.cancel() function and restart it, the old data arrays are thrown away.  I have tried to sidestep this issue by saving the "paused" array and then merging it with the "restarted" array at the end of the restarted trial, but this doesn't account for the fact that a trial could be paused numerous times.

Are the timer/timerTask classes the wrong classes to be using for this job?  Is there a better way to collect time-based data in Java?  Or am I just overlooking a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As the API specifies Timer.cancel()

> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks.

The simplest way to achieve the functionality you desire would probably be to store a 'paused' boolean and toggle it when the user pauses/unpauses.  Then check the state of the boolean from within your task and simply `return;` if the trial is paused.  The Timer will still fire every second, but nothing will happen as long as the trial is paused.